# why can't I export 'combineReducers' (imported as 'combineReducers') was not found in 'react-redux'

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Here is my main js  code and why combine all reducer
***cartredux\src\redux\reducers\main.js***

```
import {combineReducers} from "react-redux";
import { cartreducer } from "./reducer";


const rootred = combineReducers({
    cartreducer
});


export default  rootred;
```

Comment: combineReducers is from redux package not react-redux

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to Import combineReducers from redux.

import {combineReducers} from "redux"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As a comment pointed out: the `combineReducers` function is part of either the `@reduxjs/toolkit` or `redux` packages, because it's about the non-UI portion of the logic.  It's *not* part of the `react-redux` package, which is specifically about React UI integration with Redux.